# Absolute Positioning in IE8 and IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The following HTML/JS video gallery works fine on Safari, Firefox and Chrome, but fails to render properly in IE (who would have guessed)

http://vimeography.com/themes/journey/

- The thumbnails have an absolutely positioned `a` element that should appear on mouseover
- The video poster frame image has a `span` title that should be appearing over the top of the poster frame, but instead, the title appears to the right of the image.

How can I properly adjust this CSS for compatibility in IE8 and 9?

Comment: How about fixing coding errors first? http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeography.com%2Fthemes%2Fjourney%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Valid HTML is an important first step towards making IE happy.

Comment: Fixed the errors that made sense to me, still experiencing the issue